# Bootstrap columns overlap each other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html, xforms

I programmed a web application with `eXist-db` based on `XML technologies` (**XForms**, **XQuery**) and I use `Bootstrap` for the GUI.

My problem is that especially the first column overlaps the second one in an inconvient display resolution when the the containing text in one of the table cells is too long.

For that I used the `overflow-y` and `overflow-x` attribute but it seems that `Bootstrap` is not interested in that. Instead of scrollbars the width of the column expands that much that it overlaps the second column

My second problem is that it is impossible to specify the height in percent because when there are too much data presented in the table the height of the column expands beyond the height of the display.

Also in this case I want that the column expands ALWAYS 100% of the display height (not more not less) and if there are more data in this table the scrollbars should do their work but also in this case they do not work.

**Here is my code snippet:**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="orderListRepeat">
        <h3>Personenübersicht</h3>
        <div style="height: 685px; width: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll;">
            <table class="table table-hover" data-sort-order="desc">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="15%"/>
                        <th data-field="lfdNr" width="15%" data-sortable="true">Lfd. Nr.</th>
                        <th data-field="name" width="40%" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
                        <th data-field="aktiverNutzer" width="30%" data-sortable="true">aktiver Nutzer</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="person-repeat" xf:repeat-nodeset="//person">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Content
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xf:trigger appearance="minimal">
                                <xf:label ref="ref1"/>
                                <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                                    ...
                                </xf:action>
                            </xf:trigger>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xf:trigger appearance="minimal">
                                <xf:label ref="ref2"/>
                                <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                                    ...
                                </xf:action>
                            </xf:trigger>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xf:trigger appearance="minimal">
                                <xf:label ref="ref3"/>
                                <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                                    ...
                                </xf:action>
                            </xf:trigger>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="orderListRepeat">
        <h3>Details</h3>
        <div style="height: 700px; width: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll;">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Name:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xf:output ref="//person[index('person-repeat')]/name"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    ...
                </tr>
                ...
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Bereich: Aktionsübersicht einer einzelnen person -->
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="orderListRepeat">
        <h3>Process</h3>
        <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <th width="5%"/>
                    <th width="25%">Col1</th>
                    <th width="20%">Col2</th>
                    <th width="20%">Col3</th>
                    <th width="20%">Col4</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="aktion-repeat" xf:repeat-nodeset="//aktionen">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            ...
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ...
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="orderListRepeat">
        <h3>Actions</h3>
        <div>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <th width="30%">Col1</th>
                    <th width="70%">Col2</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="teilaktion-repeat" xf:repeat-nodeset="//aktionen[index('aktion-repeat')]/teilaktionen/taktion">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            ...
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ...
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*EDIT:*
@birdspider Thank you for your answer. I tried it out but it does not really work.

**Here my CSS:**

```
.orderListRepeat {
    border: solid 1px grey;
    height: 80vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

**Here is the codesnippet** of the first two tables (I tried to use the tag `<div class="col-md-3 orderListRepeat">` but if I do that every column is as wide as the complete screen and the columns are displayed among themselves but it should work anyway):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="orderListRepeat">
            <h3>Personenübersicht</h3>

            <table class="table table-hover" data-sort-order="desc">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="15%"/>
                        <th data-field="lfdNr" width="15%" data-sortable="true">Lfd. Nr.</th>
                        <th data-field="name" width="40%" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
                        <th data-field="aktiverNutzer" width="30%" data-sortable="true">aktiver Nutzer</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="person-repeat" xf:repeat-nodeset="//person">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Content
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xf:trigger appearance="minimal">
                                <xf:label ref="ref1"/>
                                <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                                    ...
                                </xf:action>
                            </xf:trigger>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xf:trigger appearance="minimal">
                                <xf:label ref="ref2"/>
                                <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                                    ...
                                </xf:action>
                            </xf:trigger>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xf:trigger appearance="minimal">
                                <xf:label ref="ref3"/>
                                <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                                    ...
                                </xf:action>
                            </xf:trigger>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="orderListRepeat">
            <h3>Details</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Name:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xf:output ref="//person[index('person-repeat')]/name"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    ...
                </tr>
                ...
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem:** The result is that the height of the columns are *at least* 80% of the height of the view right now. When the tables have too much rows the scrollbars does not work as you see in the screenshot. The problem with the overlapping columns in the width is also still existing. Confusing is that when I copy the code into codepen everything works like it should.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

something like this: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEZGzB)

the changes of note are:

css:

```
/* .orderListRepeat basicly matches the cols in my codepen code */ 
.orderListRepeat { 
  border: solid 1px grey;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

with `100vh` being 100% viewport height

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3 orderListRepeat">
      <h3>Personenübersicht</h3>
      <table class="table table-hover" data-sort-order="desc">
        <thead>
        ...
```

some removal of unneccesary nesting, style attrs and wrapping in .container

---

I'm not a frontend dev - so beware.